# Getting Missing value in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, querydsl, elasticsearch-opendistro

I am looking for a query that will return the value which is missing in the documents from the given list of values.
For example, there is a country field in the documents with values USA, Dubai, Singapore, Japan. Now I want to tell elastic search that I am giving you the list of countries(USA, Dubai, Russia), you give me the output which tells Russia is not part of any document.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a query like the one below that will only select documents with USA, Dubai and Russia and then aggregate the `country` values.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "country": [
        "USA",
        "Dubai",
        "Russia"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "countries": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "country"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the results, you're going to get buckets for all countries that are present (i.e. USA and Dubai) and no bucket for Russia.

You can then do a simple set arithmetics by subtracting the input array with the one you got from the aggregation results and you'll find what you need, i.e.:

```
[USA, Dubai, Russia] - [USA, Dubai] = [Russia]
```

**UPDATE**: If you want to do all the above in a single country you can leverage the [`scripted_metric` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html).

`map_script` is going to run for each document on a shard and store all present countries in the temporary variable `state.countries`.

`reduce_script` is going to run on the coordinating node and receives the results of all shards. That script is simply comparing which countries in the `params.countries` array are present and is going to only output the countries that are not present.

```
POST country/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "country": [
        "USA",
        "Dubai",
        "Russia"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "missing_countries": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "state.countries = [:]",
        "map_script": """
          def country = doc['country.keyword'].value;
          if (!state.countries.containsKey(country)) {
            state.countries[country] = 0;
          }
          state.countries[country]++;
        """,
        "combine_script": """
          return state.countries;
        """,
        "reduce_script": """
          // gather all present countries
          def countries = new HashSet(); 
          for (state in states) {
            countries.addAll(state.keySet());
          }
          // figure out which country in params is not present in countries
          def missing = [];
          for (country in params.countries) {
            if (!countries.contains(country)) {
              missing.add(country);
            }
          }
          return missing;
        """,
        "params": {
          "countries": ["USA", "Dubai", "Russia"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, the output is going to be

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "missing_countries" : {
      "value" : [
        "Russia"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: How do I do the set arithmetic? all I have is kibana query dashboard only. Therefore all I have to achieve using a single query only. Sorry, I am completely new to the Elasticsearch world.

Comment: it is giving syntax error at "map_script": """ . Says expected ' , ' instead of ' " '

Comment: Where are you running this ? In Kibana Dev Tools?

Comment: If not, you need to replace `"""` by `"` and inline the scripts on a single line between double quotes. Only Kibana "understands" the triple quotes `"""`

Comment: I am using the extraction query editor inside kibana alerts. Not even " helping. Let me try some more ways.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "extraction query editor inside kibana alerts" is

Comment: There is an alerting dashboard inside open distro kibana. Where you can create monitors and alerts to get notified for any abnormalities.

Comment: Ok, then it's definitely not a query you can reuse there I'm afraid... Your question didn't really mention that point